# Why when importing SVG file from inkscape to blender it's not importing anything?

Tags: svg, blender

In inkscape I saved the file as plain svg or as inkscape svg format. The file size on hard disk is about 1.59 MB

Then in blender I opened the add-ons window and searched for svg and check the first addon I also tried to check the second one but it didn't work in any case.

[image: Blender]

Then I did in blender: File > Import > Scalable Vector Graphic (.svg)
And selected the file and clicked on import SVG:

[image: Blender]

Then it's thinking for some seconds and then it's staying in the opening window showing the cube. Tt didn't load the file:

[image: Blender]

In the Inkscape I loaded/opened this jpg file:

[image: Rock inkscape]

Then selected it and then in the Inkscape I did:

Path > Trace Bitmap...

Then clicked on Update and then on OK
Then saved it as SVG and then tried to import it in blender.

[image: Rock]

The main goal is to use inkscape and blender and to convert the image to 3d object.

Comment: What's in the SVG file?

Comment: @RobertLongson Updated my question with what I did in inkscape and how I saved it to svg. The main goal is to use inkscape and blender and to convert the image to 3d object.

Comment: Starting with a bitmap is probably the wrong approach.

Comment: It's jpg what I opened in inkscape. What should I do then ?

Comment: Draw what you want in inkscape directly.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not a programming question.